How to make 'Save' Button to change the state of widget
Hye I'm quite beginner to flutter, I'm doing a page where I can change the value of inside the widget when the user tapped that particular widget. It will show display of editing  when the user and are editing, when clicked save, the display will turn back to original (which is the bold one). The problem that I have been facing is that, when I clicked the widget it can edit and when I clicked the save button it will save my input in the model but it will wouldn't change the state of the widget which is back to bold. (can check the widget file to see the widget display part)
Below I will share code of my page file and the widget file.
setting_screen.dart (page)
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:lab5/models/factory.dart';
import 'package:lab5/widgets/custom_button.dart';
import 'package:lab5/widgets/setting_detail.dart';

class SettingsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int factoryIndex;

  const SettingsPage({super.key, required this.factoryIndex});

  @override
  State<SettingsPage> createState() => _SettingsPageState();
}

class _SettingsPageState extends State<SettingsPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: SettingsPanel(factory: factories[widget.factoryIndex]),
    );
  }
}

class SettingsPanel extends StatefulWidget {
  final Factory factory;

  const SettingsPanel({super.key, required this.factory});

  @override
  State<SettingsPanel> createState() => _SettingsPanelState();
}

class _SettingsPanelState extends State<SettingsPanel> {
  bool isEditing = false;
  final TextEditingController _steamPressureController =
      TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _steamFlowController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _waterLevelController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _powerFrequencyController =
      TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _steamPressureController.text =
        widget.factory.threshold.steamPressure.toString();
    _steamFlowController.text = widget.factory.threshold.steamFlow.toString();
    _waterLevelController.text = widget.factory.threshold.waterLevel.toString();
    _powerFrequencyController.text =
        widget.factory.threshold.powerFrequency.toString();
  }

  void _updateFactoryThresholdValues() {
    setState(() {
      widget.factory.threshold.steamPressure =
          double.parse(_steamPressureController.text);
      widget.factory.threshold.steamFlow =
          double.parse(_steamFlowController.text);
      widget.factory.threshold.waterLevel =
          double.parse(_waterLevelController.text);
      widget.factory.threshold.powerFrequency =
          double.parse(_powerFrequencyController.text);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<double> values = [
      widget.factory.threshold.steamPressure,
      widget.factory.threshold.steamFlow,
      widget.factory.threshold.waterLevel,
      widget.factory.threshold.powerFrequency,
    ];

    final List<TextEditingController> controllers = [
      _steamPressureController,
      _steamFlowController,
      _waterLevelController,
      _powerFrequencyController,
    ];

    return Card(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Minimum Threshold",
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w800, fontSize: 16),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Icon(Icons.info_outline),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: LayoutBuilder(
                builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                  int crossAxisCount = constraints.maxWidth > 1024 ? 4 : 2;

                  return GridView.builder(
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: crossAxisCount,
                      childAspectRatio: 1,
                      mainAxisExtent: 150,
                    ),
                    itemCount: 4,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            isEditing = !isEditing;
                          });
                        },
                        child: SettingsDetail(
                          title: details[index],
                          value: values[index],
                          unit: units[index],
                          isEditing: isEditing,
                          onValueChanged: (newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              values[index] = newValue;
                            });
                          },
                          controller: controllers[index],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              child: CustomButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _updateFactoryThresholdValues();
                    isEditing = false;
                  });
                },
                label: const Text("Save"),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


setting_detail.dart (widget)
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:responsive_framework/responsive_framework.dart';

class SettingsDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final double value;
  final String unit;
  final bool isEditing;
  final Function(double) onValueChanged;
  final TextEditingController controller;

  const SettingsDetail({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
    required this.value,
    required this.unit,
    required this.isEditing,
    required this.onValueChanged,
    required this.controller,
  });

  @override
  State<SettingsDetail> createState() => _SettingsDetailState();
}

class _SettingsDetailState extends State<SettingsDetail> {
  bool isEditing = false;

  void _toggleEditing() {
    setState(() {
      isEditing = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: _toggleEditing,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Column(children: [
          Text(
            widget.title,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
              fontSize: ResponsiveValue(
                context,
                defaultValue: 14.0,
                conditionalValues: const [
                  Condition.smallerThan(
                    name: MOBILE,
                    value: 10.0,
                  ),
                  Condition.equals(
                    name: TABLET,
                    value: 16.0,
                  ),
                  Condition.equals(
                    name: DESKTOP,
                    value: 18.0,
                  ),
                  Condition.largerThan(
                    name: DESKTOP,
                    value: 28.0,
                  ),
                ],
              ).value,
            ),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 8,
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
            ),
            child: IntrinsicHeight(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: isEditing
                        ? TextField(
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            controller: widget.controller,
                            onChanged: (newValue) =>
                                widget.onValueChanged(double.parse(newValue)),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          )
                        : Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              widget.value.toString(),
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w800, fontSize: 20),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                          ),
                  ),
                  const VerticalDivider(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    thickness: 2.0,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      widget.unit,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800, fontSize: 12),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}


I have try to put the isEditing at the save button but it still wouldn't change the display state

I think it is a matter of scope. The isEditing of the panel is not the same isEditing of the SettingsDetail.
If you want to propagate changes, you can use a provider or simialr solution, or add a function inside the SettingsDetail that can be called from the parent when setting state to change the isEditing parameter.
Provider like solution is cleaner IMO
Correction - Before doing all of the above... Check the isEditing of settingsDetail. You are re-declaring it in the state. Use wdiget.isEdting if you want to use the incoming parameter.

thanks @0ver0n I have remove _toggleEditing and add widget.isEditing at the if statement for widget display. And the problem is solved
